# What size of fan requires motors with a transmission?

Tags: motors, fan

I am wondering at what fan size/speed a direct drive motor is no longer sufficient to drive a fan?  Phrased alternatively, what size/speed of fan requires motors with a transmission? For an axial fan.

Comment: What kind of fan? At what speed? Your question is too vague, I think. There's an [edit] link ...

Comment: Pick a size and speed of fan, and for \$10 I'll give you a good argument about why it should be direct-drive.  For another \$10 I'll give you an argument just as good for why it should be geared.

Comment: Smarty pants.  How about I pay you $30 and you answer the question as it stands as today?

Comment: @JordanMcBain So, have you paid up?

Answer (score 0):

Often because the “standard” off the shelf motor has a running speed different to the required fan speed or most efficient fan speed.

Then it comes down to a choice of transmission or motor speed control which is influenced by many other factors.

Weight

Cost

Fixed speed or variable speed

Ambient conditions

Can all be relevant.